# C# Lib to query MySQL DB

Tags: .net, mysql, ado.net, connector

Is there any good nice library to query MySQL DB? I have mysql connector .net installed, and it basically gives me ado.net replaced, like MySQLCommand, MySQLAdapter etc

```
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand ();
command.CommandText = "select * from samples";
```

but you have to write a lot of code anyway, is there any lib, that wraps up this, so I write something like

```
p = MysqlProvider.Connect();
dataSet = p.Execute(query);
```

or

```
array = p.Execute(query);
value = p.ExecuteAsValue(query);
```

etc?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for an ORM, be sure to read through: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/orm/faq

In particular [Which ORM for .NET would you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend)

Comment: Not really, I'd like to run a complex query with many joins and get a resulting set. ORM is 1:1 mapping, like LightSpeed ORM

Comment: @Dmitry, joins can be done with LINQ / NHibernate and so on. Its an abstraction so quite often the syntax is different, sometimes it is more concise sometimes it is less powerful. LINQ-to-SQL has an override that lets you execute SQL directly and map to POCO objects.  It all depends on your business problem.

Comment: LINQ2SQL doesn't work with MySQL, all others ORM that works with it - has no way to query MySQL directly and receive associated array or dataset in a return. So that's why I'm asking.

Comment: ALSO LINQ parsers sometimes produces completely wrong query. Not from performance, but from tree view. SO you get a different result set.